# Evaluating $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n-1)!}{(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)\cdots(x+n)}$ for positive real $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

Let $x$ be a positive real number. Evaluate the infinite sum
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n-1)!}{(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)\cdots(x+n)}$$

My approach was writing the expression as
$$ x!\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(n+x)}$$
Then I assumed $x=2$ then I got answer as $1/2$, so the answer was $1/x$ (for general). But can I get any idea for a generalized solution of the question?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124166/discussion-on-question-by-soumili-nag-evaluating-sum-n1-infty-fracn-1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Partial fractions approach**

You can show, via partial fractions:

$$\begin{align}\frac{(n-1)!}{(x+1)\cdots(x+n)}&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k-1}\frac{\binom{n-1}{k-1}}{x+k}\\&=\int_0^{1}t^x(1-t)^{n-1}\,dt
\end{align}$$

You could also prove this using integration by parts and induction:

$$\int_0^1 t^x(1-t)^{n-1}\,dt =\frac{n-1}{x+1}\int_0^1 t^{x+1}(1-t)^{n-2}\,dt$$
Summing, we have:

$$\begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n-1)!}{(x+1)\cdots(x+n)}&=\int_0^1 t^x\cdot \frac1{1-(1-t)}\,dx\\&=\int_{0}^1t^{x-1}\,dx\\&=\frac{1}{x}\end{align}$$

You can switch the sum and integral by the Lebesgue Monotone Convergence Theorem.

Without the monotone convergence theorem, you can just take partial sums:

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{N} &=\int_0^1 t^x\frac{1-(1-t)^N}{t}\,dt\\
&=\frac1x-\int_0^1 t^{x-1}(1-t)^N\,dt\\
&=\frac1x-\frac{N!}{x(x+1)\cdots (x+N)}\\
&=\frac1x-\frac1{x(1+x/1)(1+x/2)\cdots (1+x/N)}
\end{align}$$

And $\prod_{n=1}^N (1+x/n)\geq 1+\sum_{n=1}^N x/n$ diverges to infinity when $x>0,$ so the limit is $\frac1x.$

Comment: Yes..thanks that's how I thought about it ...

Comment: You might be able to find a telescoping sum for the general $x,$ but it won’t be as easy.

Comment: Could you please provide an upvote if you felt the question was worth it ... because stack exchange really keeps quite harsh rules .

Comment: @SOUMILINAG If that's how you thought about it why didn't you say so? In your question there's no indication of _how_ you got $1/2$ when $x=2$. Also in this answer there's nothing about how we're safe to assume it's $1/x$ since it equals $1/x$ for one or three values of $x$.

Comment: @SOUMILINAG And here the author is evaluating $\frac{1}{x!}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n-1)!}{(x+1)(x+2)\cdots(x+n)}$, which is not the same as either version of your sum.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews ...could you provide a suitable link for the use of  the monotone convergence theorem to proove the switching of summation and integral

Comment: @SOUMILINAG The Wikipedia page starting with Beppo Levi’s Lemma is okay, a bit badly rganized. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem

Comment: Another link: @SOUMILINAG http://mathonline.wikidot.com/lebesgue-s-monotone-convergence-theorem